# Issued when loading code within Rmd format in Kaggle

Tags: r, dashboard, kaggle, flexdashboard

I have some troubles with kaggle project. 
When I try to use flexdashboard package to create a interactive dashboard, The code are well received in my R studio desktop. But not in Kaggle, here are the link 2 dashboards in both rpubs and kaggle

[rpubs](https://rpubs.com/mincopxkiftu2/599552)

[kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/mybesttry/dashboard-demo-i-will-continute-later)

I hope that you can join and help me

Comment: First link shows an empty page for me.

Comment: At least overview page works, it may be caused by your env. But does character page work ?

Comment: maybe the rpubs is overloaded

Comment: I strongly supposed that the code are well recieved in R studio, but not in Kaggle